# Websphere 7 takes a very long time to deploy a war

Tags: deployment, websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to deploy a war in Websphere 7/Windows 7. 
I tried both methods, from the GUI console and from the command line. 
From the command line, I tried

```
wsadmin>$AdminApp install c:/app.war
```

In both cases it takes a VERY long time to finish, hours literally. 
There is nothing special about the application deployed, like time consuming tasks done at initialization. 
Why is that? On the same server, an update of an already existing app is finishes in minutes. 
Is there a way to make deployment faster?

Comment: How big is your app? Did you try to increase heap size?

Comment: The file is ~ 50 MB. No, I did not try to increase the heap size.

Comment: Have you tried to deploy it on another Websphere 7 server on another machine?

Comment: Yes, on a different server (same version) and different machine it still takes long.

Comment: And yes, I also increased the heap size, but no improvement.